# deprecated property: connection-timeout: 12000

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have this property into Spring Boot application:

```
server:
  connection-timeout: 12000
```

I get warning:

```
Deprecated Each server behaves differently. Use server specific properties instead. 
  Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.6.8 (spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.8.jar)
```

is there some better configuration property that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even know why you receive a deprecated warning.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3.0-Configuration-Changelog) from Spring Boot version 2.3 and onwards this property is removed not deprecated any more.

As you can read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html), there are some other properties which you can use instead depending on the server that runs your spring boot application.

`server.tomcat.connection-timeout` should be used if you have tomcat as running server.

`server.netty.connection-timeout` should be used if netty is used.

`server.jetty.connection-idle-timeout` should be used if jetty is used

Basically each server has it's own implementation, so you must read your server's documentation to see what it allows and how this behaves. There might be slight differences from how one server behaves and how it interprets connection-timeout and how another server behave and interprets a similar configuration.

This is I think the reason that Spring decides to move to server specific configuration on property `connection-timeout` instead of a general property and also **a very important reason was that some servers may not even have this configuration available to them**. So then you have a general property configured in your spring boot application which the server that runs the application can't even respect.

Therefore you now have specific properties for specific servers and now you can be sure upfront whether this configuration is available in your server and you can also read the server documentation to understand exactly what the behavior will be.

Comment: Thanks, I use `spring cloud 2021.0.3` How I can find which server is used by default?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Default embedded server in spring boot since the beginning is tomcat.

Comment: One more question: For .yml config file what should be the proper configuration? `server: tomcat: connectionTimeout: 123` or  `server: tomcat: connection-timeout: 123`?

Comment: The question is: `connectionTimeout` or `connection-timeout`?

Comment: The property as you can see in my answer above is `server.tomcat.connection-timeout`. Anything different than this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Although this setting is being deprecated, we still can use the timeout function.

According to official document, we can use `@Transactional(timeout = 1)` to do the track in the controller

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-timeout