# spring boot 3 upgrade: error in application.yml file

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have upgraded spring boot version to 3 and getting below error for the field connection-timeout in properties file,  what alternative can I use for this?

```
Property source 'Config resource 'class path resource [application.yml]' via location 'optional:classpath:/'':
    Key: server.connection-timeout
        Line: 16
        Reason: Each server behaves differently.


Please refer to the release notes or reference guide for potential alternatives.
```

Comment: "Please refer to the release notes or reference guide for potential alternatives." have you done this?

Comment: yes, I have checked this but didn't find any alternatives to field connection-timeout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [deprecated property: connection-timeout: 12000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72698754/deprecated-property-connection-timeout-12000)

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72700025/345130

In short, `server.connection-timeout` was removed in Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE.
User server-specific properties, such as `server.tomcat.connection-timeout`.